# sinusoidal signals with frequency of 5 hertz

Tags: plot, signals, frequency, degrees, phase

I want to generate and plot two sinusoidal signals with a frequency of 5 hertz and a phase difference of 60 degrees between them.
The sampling frequency should be 500 hertz and the signal length should be 1 second.
After drawing the signals, I should print the phase difference between the signals by calculating the number of samples and seconds. I have made it with seaborn library but I want to make it without library anyone can help me please ?
and my codes in figure
[image]

Comment: welcome! please try to insert code instead of pictures, it will be easier for readers

Comment: Welcome daemushin! I'm curious why you want to make it without the seaborn library? Because making plots without using any plotting library sounds needlessly difficult to me.